# Decentralized instance communication

Tags: wireless, lan

I intend to build an application that will run on several devices and its main task is storing and presenting data. This application will be deployed to several devices. These various instances should exchange and sync their data with the other instances in the (W-)LAN. However, their should be no central server and, if possible, the network infrastructure should not have to be altered.

How can I get the instances to find each other when they are in the same network? I was thinking about utilizing multicast to have the devices find each other and then establish a direct connection. Is their any other way of going about this? I would like to make the approach work on as many device types (especially smartphones and PCs) as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about programming and applications are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multicast for discovery and then a direct connection is a good approach.

Without any server there's probably no better way. Using a registration/directory server could enable the devices to find each other across subnets - often, wired LAN and Wi-fi devices sit on different subnets.

Check the local firewalls and configure them to allow receiving the discovery multicast and connecting directly.